# In transactional kafka, is it possile to find out if an offset is an actual message or a control record (a transaction commit/abort) marker message?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-transactions-api

In my project, I seek to a particular offset and then do consumer.poll

In case the offset is a control record, the poll method returns zero records. I want to know if it is because the offset has a control record or is it because of some other error which I should be aware of

Tried to find any method to check offset details but didn't find it